# Eager loading dialog boxes for close etc, especially when reviewing

Tags: feature-request

I notice that sometimes, the dialog boxes to close a question for example, takes a while to load. Often this is not a big problem, because we may not always want to close it.

However, it is most pronounced when in the Close votes review queue. Here, we may close a large number of questions, and there is a high chance of accessing the dialog. It is most obvious when we want to select the "Exact Duplicate" option, because it must load **3** pages in the dialog, and it takes like 1 second to do each request.

Often, I have already clicked the tab for exact duplicate and know what I want to vote. Can this be eager-loaded so that we don't have to wait so long?